# Naive Bays spam filtering

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spam-prevention

I am trying to implement my first spam filter using a naive bayes classifier. I am using the data provided by UCI’s machine learning data repository (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection). The data is a table of features corresponding to a few thousand spam and non-spam(ham) messages. Therefore, my features are limited to those provided by the table.

My goal is to implement a classifier that can calculate P(S∣M), the probability of being spam given a message. So far I have been using the following equation to calculate P(S∣F), the probability of being spam given a feature.

P(S∣F)=P(F∣S)/(P(F∣S)+P(F∣H))
from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering

where P(F∣S) is the probability of feature given spam and P(F∣H) is the probability of feature given ham. I am having trouble bridging the gap from knowing a P(S∣F) to P(S∣M) where M is a message and a message is simply a bag of independent features.

At a glance I want to just multiply the features together. But that would make most numbers very small, I am not sure if that is normal.

In short these are the questions I have right now.
1.) How to take a set of P(S∣F) to a P(S∣M).
2.) Once P(S∣M) has been calculated, how do I define a a threshold for my classifier?
3.) Fortunately my feature set was selected for me, how would I go about selecting or finding my own feature set?

I would also appreciate resources that might help me out as well. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use Naive Bayes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier

1. It's probably beyond the scope of this answer to explain it, but essentially you multiply the probability of each feature give spam together, and multiply that by the prior probability of spam. Then repeat for ham (i.e. multiple each feature given ham together, and multiply that by the prior probability of ham). Now you have two numbers which can be normalized to probabilities by dividing each by the total of both. That will give you the probability of S|M and S|H. Again read the article above. If you want to avoid numerical underflow, take the log of each conditional and prior probability (any base) and add, instead of multiplying the original probabilities. Adding logs is equivalent to multiplying the original numbers. This won't give you a probability number at the end, but you can still take the one with the larger value as the predicted class.
2. You should not need to set a threshold, simply classify each instance by what is more likely, spam or ham (or whichever gives you the greater log likelihood).
3. There is no simple answer to this. Using a bag of words model is reasonable for this problem. Avoid very infrequent (occurring in < 5 documents) and also very frequent words, such as the, and a. A stop word list is often used to remove these. A feature selection algorithm can also help. Removing features that are highly correlated will help, particularly with Naive Bayes, which is highly sensitive to this.